# Replacing scene causing crash on Cocos2dx

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocos2d-x

When I exit one scene, to the next, using the following code;

```
if(_next->boundingBox().containsPoint(location))
    {

        LipsColorScene::flagnext=false;
        CCLog("click next");
        _next->setVisible(false);
        _next->setPosition(ccp(1500, -500));
        lipstickscrollview->setVisible(false);
        imageForShowingMask->setVisible(false);
      //  this->setScale(1.0f);
        lipstickscrollview->setVisible(false);
        LipsColorScene::screenshot= this;
        CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getRunningScene()->removeChild(screenshot);
        lipstickscrollview->setVisible(false);
               imageForShowingMask->setVisible(false);
             //  this->setScale(1.0f);
               lipstickscrollview->setVisible(false);
      //  CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playEffect("sounds/btn_clicksound.mp3");
        CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(LastScene::scene());
    }
```

When it shows the LastScene, it crashes, the init part of LastScene is this;

```
if (LipsColorScene::screenshot !=NULL)
        {
            LipsColorScene::screenshot->setPosition(ccp(115.833313,-111.562469));
            LipsColorScene::screenshot->setRotation(-17);
            this->addChild(LipsColorScene::screenshot,0);
        }
```

If I remove this line;

```
this->addChild(LipsColorScene::screenshot,0);
```

Then the game does not crash, however, the desired result is not achieved as I need to use the screenshot.

Is there a way I can call the above method without needing to add it as a child?

Comment: What is your goal? Are you trying to keep around a node for use in the next scene?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add the invalid pointer LipsColorScene::screenshot. You'll need to retain it before replacing the scene and then release it after you add it during the init method.